# How to solve comparison of different signedness

Tags: c++

I manage to create a least used cache based on a tutorial online but I received this error below. As I have never code until that complex before, I will like to ask for advice as to how to improve the statement and what else should I look out for? I have written comments as I follow through the video so there could be some incorrect comment.

Error Message

```
comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, std::_List_iterator<int> > >::size_type' {aka 'long long unsigned int'} and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
```

Line with error

```
if(_cache.size() == _capacity){
```

LRU cache program

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class LRUCache{
public:
    LRUCache(int capacity){
        _capacity = capacity;
    }

    int get(int key){
        //auto item to find key
        auto item = _cache.find(key);

        //if key doesn't exist, return -1
        if(item == _cache.end()){
            return -1;
        }

        //if key exist, return value and update LRU
        //update iterator
        use(item);
        //return reference from iterator to order map to get second part of map value 
        return item->second.first;
        
    }

    void set(int key, int value){
        auto item = _cache.find(key);
        //if key exists, set value and update
        if(item != _cache.end()){
            //update
            use(item);
            //set value of key to something else
            _cache[key]={ value, _lru.begin() };
            return; 
        }
        //if key dont existm, check capacity       
        if(_cache.size() == _capacity){
            //kick out the LRU item  
            //find the key with back 
            _cache.erase(_lru.back());
            //kick out the key
            _lru.pop_back();
        }
            //push key to final list
            _lru.push_front(key);
            //insert new key value pair
            _cache.insert({key, { value, _lru.begin()} } );
    }

    void use(std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, std::list<int>::iterator>>::iterator& it){
        // deleting second value
        _lru.erase(it-> second.second);    
        //pushing to third value up
        _lru.push_front(it-> first);       
        //updating the iterator to latest 
        it->second.second = _lru.begin();
    }

private: 
    int _capacity;
    // order of map will be <key, <value, key iterator>>
    std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, std::list<int>::iterator>> _cache;
    // list of keys where 1st is most often used and last one is least used
    std::list<int> _lru;
     
};

int main(){
    LRUCache *cache = new LRUCache(2);
    cache->set(1,1);
    cache->set(2,2);
    std::cout << cache->get(1) <<std::endl; //shld be 1
    cache->set(3,3);
    std::cout << cache->get(2) <<std::endl; //should get -1
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Use `std::size_t _capacity;`?

Comment: Use `std::size_t` or `decltype(_cache)::size_type` instead of `int` for `_capacity`?

Comment: The `_capacity` should not be of a signed type in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for all your guidance. I manage to learn something new today. Sorry if my question is like a beginner.

Comment: The visible outcome might be on the beginner side of things, the deeper issue is definitely not. Whether using unsigned types for size and capacity is a good idea is still an open debate between experimented developers, with strong arguments on both sides.